# Trying to make a class return a string

Tags: vb.net

I'm moving code from code-behind to classes and run into a problem. I have a method which makes a string (an html invoice). In the method a final amount is created. I want to make a class called Invoice which will have the method "CreateInvoice" which will return a string and I also want to set the finalCharge property of the object. I have all the heavy lifting done but it's setting up the class is the part I'm having troubles with

```
Public Class Invoice
    Public finalCharge As Double
    Public invoiceString As String
    Public billingId As Integer
    Public clientID As Integer

Public Shared Function CreateInvoice(ByVal bill_id As Integer, ByVal client_id As Integer) As String
    ... 'create string invoice
    ... 'tally final charge
End Function


'On my code-behind page.
dim y as string
dim x as Invoice

y = x.CreateInvoice(1225,8855) <-- this line doesn't work.
```

Thank you for helping be get sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `Shared` function - which means you don't need (or want) an instance of the class to use it. You should call it like:

```
Invoice.CreateInvoice(1225, 8855)
```

That said, I'm not entirely sure it should be `Shared` to begin with, since you also state:

> [I]...want to set the finalCharge property

Since a `Shared` function can only access `Shared` properties (since there is no instance), you may *really* want it to be an instance function:

```
Public Class Invoice
    Public finalCharge As Double
    Public invoiceString As String
    Public billingId As Integer
    Public clientID As Integer

    Public Function CreateInvoice(ByVal bill_id As Integer, ByVal client_id As Integer) As String
        ... 'create string invoice
        Me.finalCharge = ... 'tally final charge
    End Function
End Class
```

In which case, you'd call it like:

```
Dim x as New Invoice()
Dim y as String = x.CreateInvoice(1225, 8855)
Dim finalCharge as Double = x.finalCharge
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I hope you don't mind if I add a follow up: In "CreateInvoice" I can't seem to set finalCharge. Inside "CreateInvoice" I have a total as double but can't seem to set the global "finalCharge". Thanks again!!